# how to grab the correct User from a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to calculate a conversion rate. However I've only been able to get it working using

```
User.first
```

however I don't really want the first user, as my app can have many. I want the specific user that is currently signed in to be that user.

Here's how the conversion rate method looks (campaign belongs to user):

campaign.rb

```
def conversion_rate
  fav = self.favorites.where(favorited: true)
  val = fav.present? ? self.favorites.where(:owner_id => User.first.followers.map(&:follower_id)).count.to_f / fav.count.to_f * 100 : 0.0
  val
end
```

what's the right method after the User here in order to find the actual user?

Comment: how you are authenticating user, are you using `devise`?

Comment: no I'm using omniauth-twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you have `current_user` in your `application_controller`

```
def current_user  
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]  
end
```

then this will be accessible in all controllers and views

So you can call `@campaign.conversion_rate(current_user)`, and pass `current_user`

```
def conversion_rate(user)
    fav = self.favorites.where(favorited: true)
    val = fav.present? ? self.favorites.where(:owner_id => user.followers.map(&:follower_id)).count.to_f / fav.count.to_f * 100 : 0.0 val  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `conversion_rate` method depends on a user. You can pass that into the method as an argument:

```
def conversion_rate(user)
  fav = self.favorites.where(favorited: true)
  val = fav.present? ? self.favorites.where(:owner_id => user.followers.map(&:follower_id)).count.to_f / fav.count.to_f * 100 : 0.0
  val
end
```

Then it is only a matter of getting the currently logged in user. This depends on your application, but a typical Rails app has a `current_user` method defined in ApplicationController. You would have to call the `conversion_rate` method at a point in your code where `current_user` is available, i.e. in a controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to get the user's ID from the current session. The details of this will vary based on how you've implemented user authentication and so on, but in general when a user logs in they'll get a session ID from your application that will be stored locally in their browser and used to track their actions while logged in. This ID is generally accessible through something like `session[:user_id]` in your application, enabling you to get the currently-logged-in user through something like `User.find(session[:user_id])`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions for more information on this. Also, if you're using an authentication library (like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or something), check in its documentation for information on how it handles sessions.